# How to limit upload bandwidth with squid server?

Tags: linux

I am using squid proxy server 3.1. I have created a rule in the delay pool for limiting downloads per user. It is working fine, but I am not able to find or create a rule for upload bandwidth. There is only a rule for max body upload; it is not useful. I want to create a rule to limit upload bandwidth per user.

Please help me; how can I create a rule for upload bandwidth?

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade squid to >= 3.2 and use "client_delay_parameters" (http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/client_delay_parameters/)